# How to send funds from an address directly to another address without using the smart contract in solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I want to able to send funds from address A to Address B(A payable address) without sending it to a smart contract as the intermediary in solidity.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `sending it to a smart contract as the intermediary in solidity`? Do you want to send ETH from an External Account A?
If that is the case, Solidity doesn't come in the picture at all right? We just send a transaction using ethers or any other library.

Comment: It is a primitive in most web3 frameworks. web3.js has `eth.sendTransaction` that can be used to send ethers to any account.